# I'm in a loop: "Sync Error: Update Sync passphrase

Tags: gmail, google-chrome, synchronization

My Chrome sync will not work. I cannot remember my pass phrase. In order to change it I am directed to my Google Dashboard which then says

> Your account seems to be empty. To start using sync, sign into your
>   Chrome browser

The link sends me back to sign into Chrome, which I can't do as there is a sync error,  and on and on. I tried looking for something or other it told me to find in my library but that wasn't there. I am not techy so this is driving me mad, I re-installed Chrome but it made no difference.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this exact same problem and it was driving me mad for 2 hours. Now I just disconnected my Google account, then signed in again, and the stupid orange exclamation mark is finally gone! there's no longer an 'update your sync passphrase' nonsense anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome uses your access credentials to encrypt your sync data, so if you have changed it, it wants you to login one more time with old access credentials. Normally you see something like "enter your password, data encrypted with the password from ".

You can set custom pass phrase to encrypt your data, so it's not connected on your google access credentials. [Here](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1181035?hl=en) is the help page about that.

Answer (score -1):

I Think i figured it out... go to the settings then disconnect your google account then just sign in again and it should be fixed.

Then you will have to sign into your Google account on your phone (if you have chrome) and enter your password then the verification code they text or email to your alternate account you had set up originally for password recovery.

Comment: Then you will have to sign into your google account on your phone (if you have chrome) and enter your password then the verification code they text or email to your alternate account you had set up originally for password recovery.

Comment: You can add the content of your comment to your answer by going to edit.